# How to put two listviews into scrollview to get them scrolling synchronized?

Tags: android

I want to put tow listviews in one scrollview on android platfrom to make both of them scrolling synchronized. For instance, when I drag the left listview up and down, the right side one would be scrolled as the same. I have tried to extend the scrollview for overriding methods but haven't get it work. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your two listview does not take many memory and has same height, try put them in single scrollview and let scrollview do scroll.

layout would be look like this:

```
<scrollview layout_width:fill_parent layout_height:wrap_content>
    <linearlayout orientation:horizontal layout_height:wrap_content layout_width:fill_parent>
         <listview layout_height:wrap_content layout_width:wrap_content layout_weight:1/>
         <listview layout_height:wrap_content layout_width:wrap_content layout_weight:1/>
    </linearlayout>
</scrollview>
```

In this case, you should set height of listview manually. you can find a solution [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm).

But if you use this solution, listview can't optimize memory usage, so listview can take much memory as item count increase.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually, I have checked out that thread before which you cliped in here. I'm about to give setting the listview layout params in adapter a shot.